# How is "soc" (UK abbr for Society) pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, slang

How is "Soc" (shortened form of "Society") pronounced in England?

I'm reading a piece of fiction set at an English university, and they keeping talking about joining societies, which they shorten to "soc". E.g. the "Writing Society" gets called "Writing Soc."

Comment: Hello, Nathan. Don't dictionaries help here?

Comment: I looked in several dictionaries and none had it as a short form for "society", only for "sociology."

Comment: @NathanHinchey If you listen to the UK pronunciation in Cambridge, it clearly says "/sɒk/ - society".

Comment: Local pronunciations for local abbreviations vary locally. I.e, there's no single way to do it. Try to listen to the natives; if you can't hear'em, make it up and be surprised later.

Comment: That comment, with a link to one of these dictionaries, would be good included in your question, Nathan. 'Negative research' is valid!

Comment: Even in 1970, my London college had plenty, including a Filmsoc, a Folksoc, and even a Gaysoc, (abbreviated and invariably referred to, thus ) and everybody pronounced it like 'sock'.

Answer (score 6):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/soc) provides both US and UK pronunciations. The UK one is /sɒk/.

There is also the pronunciation /səʊʃ/ but that ***soc*** comes from ***sociology***, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soc).

<sub>(Audio available in both links)</sub>

Comment: I've never heard  /səʊʃ/ ... have you? Sounds a bit like something Bertie Wooster would come up with.

Comment: I haven't in real life, but I did find it on YouTube while researching :)

Comment: I have exclusively heard /soʊʃ/ but that was always an abbreviation for "sociology".

Comment: Definitely pronounced *sock* for "society". But even in *1984,* Ingsoc (Newspeak for English Socialism) is pronounced "Ingsock". /soʊʃ/ is an outlier.

Comment: It's the same as the almost universal pronunciation of "spec" with a hard 'c' for "specification" or "specify" as in "Up to spec" or "Spec it out". Interestingly the word "soccer" for what almost everyone but the Americans call "football" is derived from the English term "Association Football" originally used to distinguish it from "Rugby Football" or "Rugger". Note that 'soccer' has a hard 'c' sound as opposed to 'association' which has a soft one. It's an example of the same thing.